# Is such transformed beta a known distribution?

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

I have a distribution $Y \sim 1/(1-Beta(\alpha,\beta))$.
I would like to understand its properties.

I was able to write down its density function, but I was not able to integrate it to get its mean, for example (except through simulation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Beta is mirror-symmetric $1-\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) =\mathrm{Beta}(\beta, \alpha)$, so you are essentially looking for the distribution of the reciprocal of a Beta random variable.

Also, if $X\sim \mathrm{Beta}(\beta, \alpha)$, then $1/X-1\sim\mathrm{BetaPrime}(\alpha, \beta)$, where $\mathrm{BetaPrime}$ is the [Beta prime distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution#Properties).

So, I would say that your $Y-1$ is distributed $\mathrm{BetaPrime}(\alpha, \beta)$.

Comment: + I should have seen the symmetry. I still don't follow your BetaPrime argument (certainly due to my rusty algebra), but [*here*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Moments_of_linearly-transformed.2C_product_and_inverted_random_variables) is discussed the inverse of a Beta, which tells me most of what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Now I get the BetaPrime. Thx.

Comment: Your answer allowed me to put the end on [*this answer.*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)